# Permutation and ordered statistic

Tags: probability, probability-theory, permutations, conditional-probability, order-statistics

Let $X_1,…,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables. Are these two equalities correct?

$P[X_{(2)}<x_2,…,X_{(n)}<x_n| X_{(1)}=x_1]=\\
=n!P[X_{2}<x_2,…,X_{n}<x_n| X_{1}=x_1]=\\
=n! P[X_{2}<x_2]…P[X_{n}<x_n]$

And if not, why? I am a bit confused as I don’t know if the permutations are also considering the fact that the minimum $X_{(1)}$ could be any of the $n$ variables.

Thank you.

Comment: What if we choose $x_2,\dots,x_n$ such that $P[X_2<x_2]=\dots=P[X_n<x_n]=1$?

Comment: That would be a disaster! You’re right